# Matlab gradient

Tags: matlab, gradient

In matlab, I must compute the symbolic gradient of a function `f(x)` with `x` a vector of dimension 5.

```
x=sym('x',[1,2,3,4,5]);
c=[1 2 4 3 5 3 4 5 4 3 4 34 5 6];
d=[1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1];
f =@(x) sum(-0.5*log(x(1))+x(1)*0.5*(x(2+d)/x(1)-c).^2-log(exp(x(2+d).*c+x(4+d))./(exp(x(2)*c+x(4))+exp(x(3)*c+x(5)))))
grad_f=gradient(f)
```

The message of error is :

> Undefined operator '.'' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'.
>
> Error in gradient>parse_inputs (line 146)
>           f = f.';
>
> Error in gradient (line 48)
>   [f,ndim,loc,rflag] = parse_inputs(f,varargin);

Do you know where is the error?

Comment: The docs imply that the `gradient` function takes a numerical vector, not a function handle: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html

Comment: @Dan there is a symbolic `gradient`

Comment: symbolic `gradient` accepts symbolic function `f` as input. your definition is a function handle. try removing `@(x)`  http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/gradient.html

Comment: Consider accepting teh answers if they helped you, this will help the community and future people to knwo if something is correct or not

Comment: @Anthony Hauser: Please upvote and accept ans answer. That is how SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only looking at the error message itself here. [`gradient`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/gradient.html) doesn't like function handles as input.

If I define function `f` as a pure symbolic without `@(x)` in the front

```
f =sum(-0.5*log(x(1))+x(1)*0.5*(x(2+d)/x(1)-c).^2-log(exp(x(2+d).*c+x(4+d))./(exp(x(2)*c+x(4))+exp(x(3)*c+x(5)))))
```

then typing gradient gives me a 5x1 array of symbolic expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify the symbolc variable you'd want the gradient to be calculated for, and specify f differently (have a look at the example):
https://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/gradient.html

They specify f without using function handles, because symbolic toolbox will take care of it on its own.

Also have a look at this question: [Matlab gradient and hessian computation for symbolic vector function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591277/matlab-gradient-and-hessian-computation-for-symbolic-vector-function)

---

EDIT: Damn, a little too late after Yvon's comment :-)